# Can I make a Min Z = max(a,b,c) in PuLP

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming, pulp

I was wondering if i could make a **multiple objective function** in **PuLP**, by doing this Can I make a Min Z = max(a,b,c) in PuLP, however when using this code

```
    ilp_prob = pulp.LpProblem("Miniimize Problem", pulp.LpMinimize)
    x = []
    if m >3:
        return 1,1
    for i in range(m):
        temp = []
        for j in range(len(jobs)):
            temp += [pulp.LpVariable("x_%s_%s" %((i+1),(j+1)),0,1, cat = 'Binary')]
        x+= [temp]
    ilp_prob += max([pulp.lpSum([jobs[j]*x[i][j] for j in range(len(jobs))] for i in range(m))])
    for i in range(len(jobs)):
         ilp_prob += pulp.lpSum([x[j][i] for j in range(m)])==1 
    ilp_prob.solve()
```

It just returns all 1 in x[0], and all 0 in x[0].

Comment: This problem is not related to a "multiple objective function". It just has a single objective.

Answer (score 7):

I'm pretty sure you can't just use python's (!) `max` on pulp's internal expressions! Those solvers are working on a very specific problem-specification, LP standard form, where is no concept for that!

The exception would be if pulp would overload this max-function for it's data-structures (don't know if that's possible at all in python), but i'm pretty sure pulp does not support re-formulations like that (there is some needed; as again: the target is the Standard-form).

[cvxpy](http://www.cvxpy.org) for example does not overload, but introduces customized max-functions, which internally transform your problem.

That being said: i'm surprised your code runs without a critical error. But i'm too lazy to check pulps sources here.

Have a look at the usual LP/IP formulation-guides.

A first idea would be:

**target:** `min (max(a,b,c))`

**reformulation:**

- introduce a new variable z
- add constraints:

  - `z >= a`
  - `z >= b`
  - `z >= c`
- assumption: the objective somehow want's to minimize `z` (maximizing will get you in trouble as the problem will get unbounded!)

  - this is the case here, as the final objective for our target would look like:
  - `min(z)`

**Remark:** One has to be careful that the problem will still be linear/convex (depending on the solver). In this case (our simple example; i did not check your whole model) i don't see a problem, but in more complex cases, `min(max(complex_expression))` `subjective to complex constraints`, this might introduce *non-convexity* (and can't be solved by Conic solvers incl. LP-solvers).

And just throwing a keyword in the ring: your approach/objective sounds a bit like [robust-optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robust_optimization), where usually some worst-case scenario is optimized. Not all multi-objective optimization problems are treating multiple objective-components like that.